# Is it possible to connect to SafePal with WallletConnectSwift?

Tags: ios, walletconnect

I am building an iOS dApp, and wanting to connect my App to SafePal.

I have found a way to connect Metamask and Rainbow etc.
But by using same protocol, I cannot obtain session data from SafePal.

(It seems my SafePal app is successfully connected to my iOS dApp though. Just doesn't call didConnectSession func)

Comment: Have you tried to ask SafePal team?

Comment: Yes, and I got following message.

Comment: Please try to launch any dapps like https://pancakeswap.finance on your computer, then select "connect" and "wallet connect" and try to connect your safepal app through the wallet connect option (by scanning the qrcode shown on the website with your safepal app), also you can contact the wallet connect team to understand how to implement their protocol into your app to be able to connect any wallets with wallet connect :)



You can find the wallet connect website there : https://walletconnect.org/

Comment: I guess that's the answer then.

Comment: Haha... okay...

Comment: Generally, people here are not interested to provide support for third party broken products for free.

Comment: Okay thanks. Btw I have looked through your linkedIn profile. You have impressive experience in blockchain! I'll read through your posts to learn more. Thank you.